# How many type of "Box Model" CSS have?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

How many type of "Box Model" CSS have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS3 has two box-models. `content-box` and `border-box`. `content-box` is the default.

## `content-box`

---

`content-box` is the default CSS box-model since CSS version 1. When using `content-box`, only the content of the box is taken in effect when calculating the width of the box. In the reference below, `content-box` is referred to as the W3C box model.

## `border-box`

---

`border-box` is the ported version of the Microsoft box model. In Internet Explorer 5 and below (IE6 in Quirks mode), IE considered the width of the element as being the combined width of the border, padding and content area of the box. In the reference below, `border-box` is referred to as the W3C box model.

No element uses the `border-box` box model unless specified via the `box-sizing` property, as such:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

## Reference Image

---

[image: Box Models]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is only one type of CSS box model. Early versions of Internet Explorer did have a bug where the padding and border were included in the total width, but it was still the same box model.

[image: Box Model]

Comment: Ok then is there any differences between `display:block` and `display:inline-block` box model?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid Neither of those change the box model. They change the flow of the elements.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - You're confusing yourself with the visual formatting model: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html