# What does this total width mean actually

Tags: html, css

I read a book that is called "Bulletproof Web Design" and that is something that I don't really understand. 
It says "While we have declared a width of 720px for the #nav, to indent the tabs we're also assigning left padding of 46px. Since padding is added to width of the element, the navigation's total width equals 766px."

```
#nav
{
   float:left;
   width:720;
   margin:0;
   padding:10px 0 0 46px;
   background:#FFCB2D;
}
```

I mean a width is 720px that is defined in the #nav selector and padding is 46px.
I don't know what the book mean with total width. I have never heared that expression before.
Is total width a common term that is equal width + padding?

Comment: Is this the real example code? It's missing `px`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the graphic below, you'll see that the padding contributes to the *total* width of the block:

[image]

Also, the author is using short-hand notation for the padding, which breaks down to:

```
top-padding: 10px;
right-padding: 0px;
bottom-padding: 0px;
left-padding: 46px;
```

The horizontal padding is contributing to the to the *total* width.

Comment: Commonly referred to as the 'box-model', should that term come up in your readings.

Comment: It seems as also the margin is included in total width

Comment: @user2658578 not width of the element (should you colour it with background colour), but yes total space the element is taking up for itself.

Comment: You should cite the source of the graphic.

Comment: @Alohci I did a Google images search for it; didn't visit a website. You can right-click for the source.

Comment: Oh OK. It's from the CSS 2.1 spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

When he says "Total Width" he's means the actual physical space the element is taking up. It will display at 766px on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Classic classic example of Box-Model confusion here. However, calm down. There's such a thing as total width. But with new CSS concepts, this is only valid in **content-box** Box Model. There are two other models, however, **Border-box** & **Padding-Box**

What you are referring to as never having heard of is the oldest and probably the most used for of Box Model where if you specify a certain width of an element, then padding and border widths are outside that width - all of which combine to give you **Total Width = Content Width (720px) + Padding width (20px+20px) + Border width (if any)**

However, **padding-box** box model means that even if you specify a width on the element, you will still find that the **Total width = Content Box (720-40)px + padding (20+20)px**

**Suggested Readings**

1. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
2. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/
3. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/
4. http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/box-model
5. [Types of Box Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376703/how-many-type-of-box-model-css-have)